# SetWindowsHookEx() only registering a local hook, while DLL is injected

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, interop

I have the code below in an unmanaged C++ DLL. The ToasterHook() function is called by a C# app using P/Invoke, and WndProc is overridden to trap any WM_COPYDATA messages. Process Explorer says that my DLL has been injected into other processes, but I am only receiving the WM_COPYDATA once when my form loads.

```
#pragma data_seg (".SHARED")
HHOOK g_HookHandle = 0;
HINSTANCE DllHandle; 
HOOKPROC hkprcSysMsg;
#pragma data_seg()


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int ToasterHook()
{
    if(g_HookHandle != 0) return 0;
    DllHandle = LoadLibrary(L"toasterHookDll.dll");
    hkprcSysMsg = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(DllHandle, "_ToasterInterProcFilter@12");
    g_HookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, hkprcSysMsg, DllHandle, 0);
    return 0;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
LRESULT CALLBACK ToasterInterProcFilter(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(code == HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED) {
        HWND g_ToasterReceiver = FindWindow(NULL, L"toaster");
        SendNotifyMessage(g_ToasterReceiver, WM_COPYDATA, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_HookHandle, code, wParam, lParam);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void ToasterUnHook()
{
    if(g_HookHandle == 0) return;
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_HookHandle);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Specifying the result of `GetProcAddress(DllHandle, "_ToasterInterProcFilter@12")` nor `ToasterInterProcFilter` itself for HOOKPROC seem to be working.

Comment: What you've done wrong is omitted *all* error checking.  So there is no way to find out why it doesn't work.  You probably don't check for errors either on the SetWindowsHookEx() call, way too many dots to make the call but it is notable that it doesn't appear to use a DLL handle.  Add UAC and the need to have both a 32-bit and 64-bit version of the code to make it more undiagnosable.

Comment: Actually, I removed the error checking code to make it easier to read. After LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress and SetWindowsHookEx, I check the handle and return GetLastError() if it is NULL, which it isn't. In addition, what I meant was that neither specifying the result of GetProcAddress or the callback function itself seems to work. I hope that clarifies things. The code is compiled as a 32-bit DLL, and appears to be injected into 32-bit processes. The only problem is that the callback only fires on the current thread, which indicates a problem with the HOOKPROC but that doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: Sorry, but I'd like to know, why did my question get downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending a [`WM_COPYDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message the `lParam` value *must* point to a [`COPYDATASTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. This data structure contains information such as a pointer to the data to be copied and the size of the data. Windows automatically handles the marshaling of this data so that it is accessible by the application receiving the message.

Your code is currently passing the `lParam` accompanying the `HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED`. It's possible that Windows can interpret the data it points to as a `COPYDATASTRUCT` structure but in most cases it will fail.

Comment: THANK YOU!! Instead of WM_COPYDATA I used RegisterWindowMessage to register a unique message and it worked!